# approve-transferfrom pattern between contracts

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design, remix

What is the general process-flow of approving **contract a** to spend tokens on behalf of **contract b** and how would  a sufficient function implementation look like which successfully achieves this?

For example let's consider following scenario. I created a standard ERC20 token and minted the token supply to **contract a**. Now I want to allow **contract b** to spend the minted ERC20 tokens on behalf **contract a**

Answer (score 2):

If **contract A** owns tokens and you want **contract B** to spend then **contract A** has to `approve` **contract B**. And **contract B** has to use `transferFrom` with.

```
contract A {
  ERC20 token; // <--- generic ERC20 token contract
  B seller;    // <--- ticket seller accepts ERC20 tokens

  event TicketPurchased(uint);

  function buyTicket(uint amount) public {

    // Contract A approves the seller to transfer tokens
    token.approve(address(seller), amount);

    // Call seller for it to transfer tokens
    uint ticketId = seller.buyTicket(amount);

    // Generate event with ticket id to capture from UI
    emit TicketPurchased(ticketId);
  }
}

contract B {
  address wallet;   // <--- wallet where tokens from purchases will be moved to
  ERC20 token;      // <--- generic erc20 token

  function buyTicket(uint amount) public returns (uint) {

    // Transfer tokens from the caller to wallet
    // (here msg.sender will be Contract A)
    token.transferFrom(msg.sender, wallet, amount);

    return 1;   // <--- ticket id
  }
}
```